# 3D array writing and reading as texture in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

Due to the nature of the algorithm I am programming I need to write/fill a 3D matrix with some specific maths and then read from that matrix (in a separate kernel) as a 3D linearly interpolated texture.

As texture is a reading mode, I am assuming I can somehow write in the global memory bind to the texture, and in a separate read from it, without the need of double memory and copying the values from the write to the read matrix.  However I don't seem to figure out how to do this.

- How can I use 3D texture memory as read and write (in separate kernels) ?

My problem is that I don't know how to define this global read/write array. In the sample below, I have created a 3D texture, but this is using code with `cudaExtent` and `cudaArray`. But I don't seem to be able to use this types to write on them, neither I seem to be able to create them with `float*` or the likes.

I may not be able to do this and need a `memcpy` somewhere in the middle, but as these arrays are generally big, I'd like to save memory.

Sample code (doesn't compile, but clearly defines the structure of what I am trying to do). Uses 100x100x100 3D memory as default because yes.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#define MAXTREADS 1024

cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size);
texture<float, cudaTextureType3D, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;

__global__ void readKernel(float* imageend )
{
    int indY = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int indX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int indZ = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    //Make sure we dont go out of bounds
    size_t idx = indZ * 100 * 100 + indY * 100 + indX;
    if (indX >= 100 | indY >= 100 | indZ >= 100)
        return;
    imageend[idx] = tex3D(tex, indX + 0.5, indY + 0.5, indZ + 0.5);

}
__global__ void writeKernel(float* imageaux){
    int indY = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int indX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int indZ = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    //Make sure we dont go out of bounds
    size_t idx = indZ * 100 * 100 + indY * 100 + indX;
    if (indX >= 100 | indY >= 100 | indZ >= 100)
        return;
    imageaux[idx] = (float)idx;

}
int main()
{

    cudaArray *d_image_aux= 0;
    const cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent(100, 100, 100);
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_image_aux, &channelDesc, extent);

    // Configure texture options
    tex.normalized = false;
    tex.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
    tex.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeBorder;
    tex.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeBorder;
    tex.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeBorder;

    cudaBindTextureToArray(tex, d_image_aux, channelDesc);

    float *d_image_end = 0;
    size_t num_bytes = 100 * 100 * 100 * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_image_end, num_bytes);
    cudaMemset(d_image_end, 0, num_bytes);

    int divx, divy, divz; //Irrelevant for the demo, important for the main code
    divx = 32;
    divy = 32;
    divz = 1;
    dim3 grid((100 + divx - 1) / divx,
        (100 + divy - 1) / divy,
        (100 + divz - 1) / divz);
    dim3 block(divx, divy, divz);

    // Kernels
    writeKernel << <grid, block >> >(d_image_aux);
    readKernel  << <grid, block >> >(d_image_end);


    cudaUnbindTexture(tex);
    cudaFree(d_image_aux);
    cudaFree(d_image_end);

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** I am aware that I can not write "interpolated" or whatever that would be. The write operation will always be in integer indexes, while the read operation needs to use trilinear interpolation.

Comment: You don't want to use a texture for this. You want to use a surface.

Comment: @talonmies hum, I had no idea of the existence of those, I'd need to research a bit more. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @talonmies I think the community would benefit from a complete answer on how to use these things. I'd like to ask you to consider adding one, as you are quite an expert in the field. Else I will try to research it more and add one in the following week.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the CUDA sample codes for writing to a 3D surface?  How about [this one](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#volumetric-filtering-with-3d-textures-and-surface-writes):  "volumeFiltering - Volumetric Filtering with 3D Textures and Surface Writes -- This sample demonstrates 3D Volumetric Filtering using 3D Textures and 3D Surface Writes."

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks or the link! I will definitely try, I didn't even know what surfaces were when I posted, hard to try examples of them!

Comment: Well, your question was about CUDA Textures.  If you look at the CUDA Texture sample codes, you'll trip over surfaces pretty quick.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I think I'll pass. There are already examples in the samples that NVIDIA ship and a whole section of the programming guide you obviously missed. There are also existing questions on [SO] about surfaces. I am more of a mind to find a duplicate and close this. But if you want to do some research and come back and write an answer I'll happily leave this open and upvote it when you are done

Comment: @talonmies Yes you are completely right. If there is a clear duplicate, please go mark it and I myself will close it. Else, I rather leave it, research and put it here.

Comment: @talonmies sorry to bother, but I can not find any documentation on the memory access filter of the surface, as it doesnt contain the `fitermode` enum, as textures do. Also, the accessing is performed in bytes, which hint that maybe I can not really access a surface using trillinear interpolation. My tests at least also hint that. I can access everything with integer indexes, but not with floating point ones.When I change the first index to a float, the memread is wrong, the others round to integers. Are you sure that surfaces is what I need?Can you help me find how to set up the filtermode?

Comment: @RobertCrovella @talonmies , none of the surface read functions in the programming guide section B.9 accept `float` type as index when reading. I don't think surface is what I need.

Comment: I didn't suggest you could do texturing from surfaces.  I suggested you look at the volumeFiltering cuda sample code, which uses both a 3D texture and a 3D surface - the surface is used for writing 3D data and the texture is used for texturing. The "missing pieces" would be to bind the underlying cuda array to your surface, call your surface writing kernel, then bind the underlying cuda array to the texture, then call your texture reading kernel.  But all the bits and pieces including the binding functions are included in that sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe all of the necessary pieces to demonstrate a kernel writing to a 3D surface (bound to an underlying 3D cudaArray), followed by another kernel texturing (i.e. with auto interpolation) from the same data (a 3D texture bound to the same underlying 3D cudaArray) are contained in the [volumeFiltering CUDA sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#volumetric-filtering-with-3d-textures-and-surface-writes).

The only conceptual difference is the sample code has 2 different underlying 3D cudaArrays (one for the texture, one for the surface) but we can combine these, so that the data written to the surface is subsequently read during the texturing operation.

Here's a fully worked example:

```
$ cat texsurf.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>

texture<float, cudaTextureType3D, cudaReadModeElementType>  volumeTexIn;
surface<void,  3>                                    volumeTexOut;

__global__ void
surf_write(float *data,cudaExtent volumeSize)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int z = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (x >= volumeSize.width || y >= volumeSize.height || z >= volumeSize.depth)
    {
        return;
    }
    float output = data[z*(volumeSize.width*volumeSize.height)+y*(volumeSize.width)+x];
    // surface writes need byte offsets for x!
    surf3Dwrite(output,volumeTexOut,x * sizeof(float),y,z);

}

__global__ void
tex_read(float x, float y, float z){
    printf("x: %f, y: %f, z:%f, val: %f\n", x,y,z,tex3D(volumeTexIn,x,y,z));
}

void runtest(float *data, cudaExtent vol, float x, float y, float z)
{
    // create 3D array
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaArray_t content;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc3DArray(&content, &channelDesc, vol, cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore));

    // copy data to device
    float *d_data;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_data, vol.width*vol.height*vol.depth*sizeof(float)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, vol.width*vol.height*vol.depth*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    dim3 blockSize(8,8,8);
    dim3 gridSize((vol.width+7)/8,(vol.height+7)/8,(vol.depth+7)/8);
    volumeTexIn.filterMode     = cudaFilterModeLinear;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaBindSurfaceToArray(volumeTexOut,content));
    surf_write<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_data, vol);
    // bind array to 3D texture
    checkCudaErrors(cudaBindTextureToArray(volumeTexIn, content));
    tex_read<<<1,1>>>(x, y, z);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    cudaFreeArray(content);
    cudaFree(d_data);
    return;
}

int main(){
   const int dim = 8;
   float *data = (float *)malloc(dim*dim*dim*sizeof(float));
   for (int z = 0; z < dim; z++)
     for (int y = 0; y < dim; y++)
       for (int x = 0; x < dim; x++)
         data[z*dim*dim+y*dim+x] = z*100+y*10+x;
   cudaExtent vol = {dim,dim,dim};
   runtest(data, vol, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
   runtest(data, vol, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6);
   return 0;
}


$ nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc texsurf.cu -o texsurf
$ cuda-memcheck ./texsurf
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
x: 1.500000, y: 1.500000, z:1.500000, val: 111.000000
x: 1.600000, y: 1.600000, z:1.600000, val: 122.234375
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

I'm not going to try to give a full tutorial on linear texture filtering here.  There are plenty of other example questions here which cover the details of indexing and filtering, and it doesn't seem to be the crux of this question.  I've chosen the points (1.5, 1.5, 1.5) and (1.6, 1.6, 1.6) for easy verification of the underlying data; the results make sense to me.

Comment: Thank you, this works fantastically. Do you know any good *tutorial* explaining the principles of surface memory? I assume it creates a cache for writing and goes writing on memory while the cores do something else, am I right? I ask, because the documentation is there, but it has no explanation on the underlying principle on how things work (or I haven't seen it). Thank you very much again, and keep doing the brilliant work.

Comment: No, I don't really know of documentation that explains in detail how surface memory works.  The best I can come up with is something like slide 14 [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/texture_webinar_aug_2011.pdf) but that is still a pretty superficial treatement.  The programming guide has various sections that cover surface use, such as [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#surface-memory) but again it is mostly covering API level functionality.

Comment: Well, thats a pity. Thank you for the links and the answer!