# looking for an efficient way to convert cudaSurfaceObject_t into a cudaTextureObject_t

Tags: cuda

I am about to write some code that will start with a pitch linear **float** array, which will be loaded into Device memory, analysed, altered and then turned into a readonly texture object of the same dimensions.
I think the best way to do this would be to create a **cudaSurfaceObject_t** from the floats, do the work on that and then convert that surface object into a **cudaTextureObject_t** on the card.

My problem is that I only know how to create a texture from a float array; I don't know of a way of creating one from the surface object without copying the array back to the host and creating a texture object from that...

Is there anyway to do this on the card without the overhead of copying?

I suspect that this is something that can be done using the underlying **cudaArray** object but I don't know enough to know how.

Comment: I'm 99% sure you can't "convert" between surfaces and textures

Comment: @talonmies, Thanks - I thought not. If I was to keep the data as a surface would there be a performance hit further down the line when I was accessing the stored data.
I.e. is accessing a surface slower than accessing a texture? or is it just as quick?
Finally, is there a book or a web site where I can research this sort of question without bothering you? Cheers

Comment: All these features are just CUDA exposing some of what Direct3D spec levels mandate. If you want to understand what is possible and what is not, and what is performant and what is not, you would be far better served using the rendering API documentation and literature as a starting point. Then come back to CUDA afterwards.

Comment: I think your question is arguably a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701467/3d-array-writing-and-reading-as-texture-in-cuda) with the arguable difference being that  you are referring to objects whereas the answer there uses references.  However that is pretty much a mechanical difference.  All the concepts are there, IMO.  And, as indicated, nearly everything you need is already present in a CUDA sample code.

Comment: @RobertCrovella - Thank you - I will study the examples that you have provided and then write up a proper answer to my question. From a casual examination I believe that you have answered my question.

Comment: @talonmies.  Thank you. I have been trying to avoid getting too deep into Direct3D etc, but I guess a trip down that particular rabbit hole is now called for. Lots to read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to my question is that yes it is possible to create a texture object from a surface object by using the underlying cudaArray object.

The process is:-

1. take the starting array and copy it onto the device.
2. Create a cudaArray_t object of the correct dimensions.
3. Create a surfaceObject_t from the cudaArray_t.
4. Map the oringinal data into the surface (kernel 1).
5. Process the surface as required (kernel 2).
6. Bind the same cudaArray object to a texture object.
7. Access the texture as normal (kernel 3).

I am not posting code here because I think that the example @RobertCrovella shared in the comments has all the information that is needed to understand this
That link is reposted here [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701467/3d-array-writing-and-reading-as-texture-in-cuda)

Note that @talonmies is also correct in his comments - you cannot convert from surface to texture.  However, you can create a texture from the underlying cudaArray attached to that surface.

I am off for some more background reading.